# Dynamically add Images to slider in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am learning and making a small project in Php, Html jquery.

I want a slider with vertical Scroll. The db will fetch an array of rows from table and get the link of the image placed on the server. It will then show load and show these images

Here is my div class

```
<div class="albums-div">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/smalimg.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/smalimg.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/smalimg.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/smalimg.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now its hardcoded but how can i dynamically create

```
<li>
            <img src="images/smalimg.png" />
        </li>
```

Comment: This is a large question. How are you inputing these things? You'll need an entire CRUD setup and tons of stuff for this. Have you thought about using a CMS that already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're returning your SQL results in a variable called $rows and that the image link is stored as "images/smalimg.png":

```
<div class="albums-div">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php 
            foreach($rows as $row){
                echo '<li><img src="' . $row['link'] . '" /></li>';
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli or prepared statements, I will show you using mysqli:

Table name: images contains

- image_id ( int - auto increment - unsigned - no default )
- image_link ( varchar - 100 length - no default )

  ```
  <?php

   $dbc = mysqli_connect("DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");

   $query = "SELECT image_link FROM images";
   $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    // Do your ouput
    echo '<li>' . $row['image_link'] . '</li>';
   }

   mysqli_close($dbc);
   ?>
  ```

EDIT: Replace the connection names above with your database specific connection values.